# How to display default footer links for my magento store?

Tags: magento-1.9, footer-links

I installed new theme for my magento 1.9.0.1 but now the default footer links(sitemap,search terms,advanced search,my account ,order and returns) are disabled.how to display these menus in footer...

Answer (score 1):

The footer links may differ from template to template. You can find them in the Magento admin panel -> CMS -> Static blocks. Each Magento store includes static blocks called Footer Links.

- About Us
- Customer Service
- Template Settings
  Privacy Policy

Try this solution..

Comment: i displayed already the above links you mentioned. but i want to display other links i mentioned above..so,please help me how to do this??

Comment: Add below to page.xml

<reference name="footer_links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalogsearch" ifconfig="catalog/seo/search_terms">
        <label>Search Terms</label>
        <url helper="catalogsearch/getSearchTermUrl" />
        <title>Search Terms</title>
    </action>
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalogsearch">
        <label>Advanced Search</label>
        <url helper="catalogsearch/getAdvancedSearchUrl" />
        <title>Advanced Search</title>
    </action>
</reference>

Comment: but it does not display in footer

Comment: can you please show your static block code..

Comment: its works @kalidas but it displays as list i want to display as a block(grid view in footer)